# How to remove whitespaces at certain sections of a text in Python?

Tags: python

I have a text which looks like below

```
        High     MM Pol Ag to SO Pol Ag
```

As you can see, there is a whitespace in the beginning, then a word and again some whitespace and then the rest of the text.

What I want is this piece of text `MM Pol Ag to SO Pol Ag`.

Now I can use `strip` to remove the leading and ending whitespaces like below.

```
text = text.strip()

High     MM Pol Ag to SO Pol Ag
```

But the white space after `High` is varying ie it can sometimes be two spaces or four or maybe more.

How can I get the required text?

**Note**: The text can vary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split your string to remove spaces, then reconstruct it ignoring the first word:

```py
>>> text = "        High     MM Pol Ag to SO Pol Ag"
>>> " ".join(text.split()[1:])
'MM Pol Ag to SO Pol Ag'
```

or, using a `regex`

```py
>>> import re
>>> re.match("^\s*\w*\s*(.*)", text).group(1)
'MM Pol Ag to SO Pol Ag'
```

Answer (score 1):

[`split()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) takes a `maxsplit` argument. This lets you split off just one piece of text and not split the rest:

```
s = "        High     MM Pol Ag to SO Pol Ag"

val = s.split(maxsplit=1)[1]  
print(val)
# 'MM Pol Ag to SO Pol Ag'
```

This lets you avoid creating a temp list and rejoining it to a string.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go (use the `split()` method to get an array of strings):

```
s = "High     MM Pol Ag to SO Pol Ag"
    
s_new = ''.join([str(elem)+' ' for elem in s.split(' ')[5:]])

print(s_new)
```

Output:

```
MM Pol Ag to SO Pol Ag
```

Comment: From the question: `Note: The text can vary.`. This would only work if the first word is 4 characters long as in `High`. Also this is unnecessarily complex, you could have simply written `text.strip()[5:].strip()`.